# Why does this button not shown

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a footer under view pager but it doesn't appear at all, i have no idea why? here is what i tried, i added the button under view pager but it doesn't appear !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_survay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ferani">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/survey_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_round"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="التالي" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this looks like an invalid layout. I see 3 `LinearLayout` opening tags but only 2 closing tags

Comment: Well, it's a piece of code not a full code , i have edited my code Please advise

Comment: @HabooltakAna If that's just a snippet of the full code, all I can say is that - you are missing a `</LinearLayout>` If your full code includes that missing piece, then its something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
No Need to use three Nested Linear Layout. Try this one:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_survay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/txt_color_white"
>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/survey_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/login"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="التالي" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will try to do that thank you :) 
but this layout will not be as root because there are a lot of component there which are doesn't appear in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your viewPager is at match_parent while the button has match_parent too and have a weight

You should try to put 0dp to the width and set a weight to both of them
also your second linear layout seems useless since by default it will apply a vertical orientation

Comment: i added weight to footer but it doesn't appear at all